# Why do I have to omit SQLEXPRESS when connecting from remote machine

Tags: sql-server

I tried to connect to my remote `SERVER\SQLEXPRESS` for a couple of minutes, after I enabled TCP/IP with Port 1433 and Named Pipes.

However, it will only connect when I omit the `SQLEXPRESS`, so I only use `SERVER` as the instance.

What's the reason for that?

Comment: First, it seems the remote instance is listening on the default 1433 port so the instance name is not needed. The only reason to specify an instance name if you need to connect to a different named instance on the machine by instance name, which requires the SQL Server Browser service to be running and UDP port 1434 allowed through the firewall.

Comment: Are you talking about a **default** or **named** instance? how are you connecting locally?